# VBA: How do I fire onclick event with no IDs or Names on image?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to fire an onclick event for an imagine in IE using VBA. The Image only has Onclick, alt, and src. I am not sure how to loop through to the image and then fire the onclick.

I have already tried looping through a few different ways, but none of the solutions work for my specific case. Typically, they involve having inner text, which I do not.

Excel VBA (This is wrong, but I'd like something like this)

```
  Dim elements As Object, element As Object
    Set elements = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")

    For Each element In elements
    If element.innerText = "Export to Excel" Then
        element.Click
    End If
    Next
```

---

JavaScript

```
function fnForecast_Export() {
    try {
        var sSearch = txtSearch.value.trim().sqlEscape().xmlToSpecial();
        if (sSearch === "") {fnGlobal_Alert(g_sBLANKSEARCH); return;}

        var sSQL = "qryGetCustomerForecastList 'SearchExport','" + fnSQLWild(sSearch, false) + "','" +
            txtStartDate.value + "','" + txtEndDate.value + "'," + drpCustomer.value + "," +
            drpPlant.value + "," + g_iPageID + ",'" + drpSortOrder.value + "'," + drpSortDirection.value;

        var sURL = g_sAppPath + "forecasting/ForecastExportWindow.asp" +
            "?Rnd=" + Math.random() +
            "&PageName=Customer" +
            "&SQL=" + sSQL +
            "&StartDate=" + g_sStartDate +
            "&EndDate=" + g_sEndDate;

        top.fraHeader.fnWait("Exporting...", "", 15000);

        var oFrame = document.getElementById("fraExportFrame");

        if (oFrame !== null) {
            oFrame.src = sURL;
        } else {
            var oNewFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            oNewFrame.id = "fraExportFrame";
            oNewFrame.src = sURL;
            oNewFrame.style.height = "0px";
            oNewFrame.style.width = "0px";
            document.appendChild(oNewFrame);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        fnErrorHandler(e, "");
    }}
```

---

HTML

```
<TD id=tdBlock class=tdCriteriaBlock noWrap>&nbsp;
<IMG onclick=fnForecast_Search(); alt=Search src="/PE372/images/search.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<IMG onclick=fnForecast_Export(); alt="Export to Excel" src="/PE372/images/excel.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<IMG onclick=fnForecast_SearchClear(); alt="Clear Search Criteria" src="/PE372/images/eraser.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
```

I would like for the "fnForecast_Export()" function in the webpage's javascript to run.

Comment: ieDoc.parentWindow.execScript "fnForecast_Export();"

Comment: ieDoc.querySelector("[alt='Export to Excel']").FireEvent "onclick"   or just ieDoc.querySelector("[alt='Export to Excel']").click   Try those and if work let me know as I can close as a duplicate.

Comment: I've tried all of the recommendations you've given. The first executing the javascript still gives the 80020101 error. I have some javascript execution in the code already, but this just does not work for some reason. The other two recommendations are both giving me the "Object doesn't support this property or method error". Is ".querySelector" proper to use with HTMLDocument?

Comment: querySelector is a method of HTMDocument. It is worth going IE > Emulation tab> checking document mode. It should be the latest possible e.g. Edge | 11 etc...   A final alternative is ieDoc.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector(""[alt='Export to Excel']"").click();"  But again - check doc mode.

Comment: The document mode is set to compatibility mode for the webpage. The page will only run on document mode 5. It will not work with 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use querySelector then you will need to try the long way with a loop and account for being in a frame tag.

```
Dim imgs As Object, img As MSHTML.HTMLImg
Set imgs = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("img") 'you may need to change index from 0 to appropriate one.
For Each img In imgs
    If img.hasAttribute("alt") Then
        If img.getAttribute("alt") = "Export to Excel" Then
            ''choose your option
            img.Click
            'img.FireEvent "onclick"
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: There is no error, but the Loop is completely skipped over. The code runs to the "For Each" line, and then  moves past the loop. I'm curious if it is not detecting any objects with tag name "img".

Comment: what value do you get for imgs.length? And does this change if you execute your code line by line with F8 slowly waiting for page load?

Comment: Okay so I have added a dowhile loop to wait for the page to load before executing the loop. That seems to have helped, but now I am getting a run-time error 70 "permission denied". This happens when use the img.length or run the loop. I am guessing that the page is protected?

Comment: on which line please?

Comment: on  the imgs.length line.

Comment: where did you put that? Straight after Set imgs = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")  ?

Comment: I rearranged the set imgs line, and now i no longer get the permission denied error. But, the imgs.length is equal to 0.

Comment: even when stepping through with F8? If that is still the case then you need to check if imgs are within a parent frame/iframe. You also don't need    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop  within the For Each Loop.

Comment: My mistake. I accidentally pasted the Do While loop there. Ahhhh, yes the images are within a frame. it is also inside a td. If that matters.

Comment: what happens with  Set imgs = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).getElementsByTagName("img")  ? check if that is right index for frame. You may need  Set imgs = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1.getElementsByTagName("img") or a higher number.

Comment: Thank you so much! I set imgs to search for frame then loop through imgs within the frame and now the function executes.

Comment: I updated answer and fixed the missing contentDocument typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Set frame to destination frame in webpage
Set frame = ieDoc.getElementsByName("fraMain")(0) 'change fraMain to your specific frame

'set ieDoc to content within specified frame
Set ieDoc = frame.contentDocument

'Set imgs to objects with tagname "img"
Set imgs = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")

For Each img In imgs
        If img.hasAttribute("alt") Then
            If img.getAttribute("alt") = "Export to Excel" Then 'change "Export to Excel" to your specific alt.
                ''choose your option
                'img.Click
                img.FireEvent "onclick"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
Next
```